# Checbox not checked in Prime

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an array of objects `testTypeMasterData`, creating checkboxes for each object. I'm not able to preselect checkbox. but If It shows value in HTML.

```
<div class="row" 
  *ngFor="let testType of testTypeMasterData">
    <div class="col col-md-8" *ngIf="testType.flgStdtest">
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-8">
             <p-checkbox 
              name="testTypes" 
              value="{{testType.id}}" 
              label="{{l(testType.testType)}}" 
              [(ngModel)]="selectedtestTypes" 
              (onChange)="testTypeChanged($event)">
             </p-checkbox>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   Selected Categories: 
   <span *ngFor="let cat of selectedtestTypes" style="margin-
   right:10px">
      {{cat}} 
   </span>
</div>

 @Input() testTypeMasterData: testTypeDetailsDTO[];


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedTenderTypes = [25];
```

[image]

`test12` value is 25. I'm setting `testTypeMasterData` in parent component.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._commonService.getTestTypeMasterData().subscribe((result) => {
        this.testTypeMasterData = result;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your example and effectively it doesn't work... But if you only change this : `this.selectedTenderTypes = ['25'];`, it should works fine.

The primeng doc indicate that `value` attribute can be `any` type, but it probably transforms it in a `string`. I guess that's why making the above modification works...